# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'host')

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am trying to connect my application to MongoDB, but getting this error 'Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'host')'.  Not able to figure out what might be the problem.

**Here is the .env file**

```
PORT=5000;
MONGO_URI ='mongodb+srv://sakshi_0630:<password>@cluster0.lxchu.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

**db.js file**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const colors = require("colors");
const connectDB=async()=>{
    try {
        const conn = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: true,
        });
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`.red.bold);
        process.exit();
    }
};
module.exports= connectDB;
```

**server.js**

```
const { response } = require("express");
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const { chats } = require("./data/data");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

dotenv.config();
connectDB();
const app = express();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the `mongoose.connect()` function

```
const connectDB = async() => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: true,
        });
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`.red.bold);
        process.exit();
    }
};
```

or use a callback function

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: true,
})
.then((conn) => {
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline);
    //do other things
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`.red.bold);
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: On doing const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, I am getting the following error: "Error: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string."

Comment: @sakshijain That would mean your application wasn't able to find `MONGO_URI` in your env file. You have a space before the `=` when defining `MONGO_URI`. Try removing the space. You can also remove the semicolon after `PORT`. Semicolons are not required in env files.

Comment: The same problem still exists.

Comment: @sakshijain The issue that remains is related to your env files, not the issue you originally posted about. Please mark this as the correct answer as this seems to have solved your original issue.